# Условие для вложенных элементов и определение маски в ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как переписать данное условие под все ссылки внутри определенного блока или маркированного списка с классом? Или же определить что `element` находится внутри определенного класса?

```
if (element.classList.contains('cat-name')) {
    return false;
}
```

Можно ли такое условие использовать для нескольких блоков с разными классами? Правильно ли использовать .querySelectorAll?

Так же, как можно определить ссылки такого вида?

```
<a href="/index/0-0-0-1-13">
```

То есть, можно ли привязаться к такой схеме: х-х-х-х-х. Где вместо нулей идут разные цифры.

За примеры отдельное спасибо!

Comment: Не очень понял, что вы хотите

Answer (score 2):

> все ссылки внутри определенного блока или маркированного списка с классом?

Можно придумать достаточно много путей, чтобы найти ссылки внутри какого либо элемента. К примеру, можно просто написать нужный [селектор](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), либо использовать методы [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), либо [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) который проводит поиск только среди потомков первого уровня.

```
$("ol.targetClassName a")   //перечень ссылок внутри списка с классов targetClassName
$("ol.targetClassName").find("a") // то же самое через find()
```

> Или же определить что element находится внутри определенного класса

Для этих целей необходимо пройтись вверх по дереву DOM. Можно использовать метод [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) возвращающий всех родителей с нужным селектором, либо [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), возвращающий ближайшей узел вверх по иерархии, удовлетворяющий условию. Если таковые элементы найдутся (число найденных больше или равно 1), значит содержится внури.

```
var contains = element.closest(".cat-name").length == 1;
var contains = element.parents(".cat-name").length > 0;
```

Здесь `element` это переменная `jQuery`.

> Так же, как можно определить ссылки такого вида?

В данном вопросе на помощь вам придут регулярные выражения. Необходимо найти все ссылки, и отфильтровать полученные используя метод коллекции [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Данный метод в качестве параметра получает ссылку на функцию обратного вызова (callback), которая непосредственно осуществляет фильтрацию, возвращая `true` если элемент подходит, и `false` в противном случае. На основании этого значения наша ссылка будет или не будет попадать в результат. Самое простое регулярное выражение для описание подобной ссылки будет иметь вид `/^\/index\/([\d-]+)$/i`. Если кратко то `^` и `$` тут обозначают начало и конец строки, `\/` экранированные слэши, `index` это начало ссылки, а с флагом `i` в конце поиск будет регистронезависимый, `([\d-]+)` - группа более одного символа,состоящая из числовых значений `\d` или знака минус. Все выражение до флагов заключается в `//`. Как я уже написал, это самое простое выражение, поэтому под него попадут и ссылки вида `/index/0`, `index/0--` и т.п., но прочие будут отфильтрованы. Возможно для вашей задачи хватит и этого.

Код, приведенный ниже, находит такие ссылки и заменяет их тестовое описание.

```
$("a").filter(function(idx, el){    
    var re = /^\/index\/([\d-]+)$/i;
    return re.test($(el).attr('href'));
}).text("found!");
```

можно немного усложнить выражение, написав `(\d+\-){4}\d+`, такое выражение будет соответствовать маске из четырех групп *число-тире*, и еще одному числу.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ. Очень подробно все описали. Скажите, а можно ли заменить последний пример на вот такую запись? `element.href.indexOf('/index/0-0-0-1-13') > -1`? То есть, извлечь все ссылки по этой схеме через .indexOf?

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev `indexOf()` вам скажет, входит содержит ли ссылка эту конкретную строку, но вам то нужны были все строки такого вида.

Comment: дело в том, что в условии я обращаюсь к конкретной ссылке. У нас есть `element` (это наша ссылка), есть `href` и отталкиваясь от этой конкретной ссылки мы строим условие. Через `.classList` или `.indexOf` я без труда отключаю любую ссылку, но вот попытки внедрить один из ваших вариантов, не увенчались успехом. Скорее всего я просто неверно составляю условие. Возможно вы запишите ваш второй пример с условием, как в примере из моего вопроса?

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev я, если честно, не понял что вы хотите сделать. Лучше в вопросе приведите пример вашей html-разметки, и опишите чего конкретно хотите добиться.

Comment: Речь идет о скрипте [barba.js](http://barbajs.org). В [этой части](https://github.com/luruke/barba.js/blob/master/dist/barba.js#L1314) описываются условия, при которых нажатие на ссылку не воспроизводит функцию. В вызывающем скрипте можно дописать свою логику поведения при клике, [тут](http://barbajs.org/faq.html) подробнее описано. То есть, во внимание берется не поиск ссылок по определенным условиям, а именно проверка конкретной ссылки. Тут есть тестовый [пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/McOROzi0kOqIhLeVQkFT?p=preview) для проб и ошибок. На "About us" есть ссылки, а редактирование в init-barba